# Как подставить переменную из цикла в sql запрос

Tags: php, sql

Собственно проблема в том, что переменная `$em` не хочет подставлять в запрос нужное значение `Email`. Если я делаю `echo $em;` - все ок, все значения выводит, а вот в запрос не хочет подставляться и возвращает мне нули.

Вероятно я накосячил с самим запросом или не верно засовываю из ассоциативного массива данные в `sql` запрос.

Пробовал привести каждое значение `em` в строковый формат, но и это не помогло.

```
<?php
  session_start();


  $tempuser = $_SESSION['email'];
  $sdd_db_host='localhost';//Имя хоста
  $sdd_db_name='m';//Название бд
  $sdd_db_user='m';//Пользователь
  $sdd_db_pass='123123';//Пароль

  @mysql_connect($sdd_db_host,$sdd_db_user,$sdd_db_pass);//Подключение
  @mysql_select_db($sdd_db_name);//Выбор базы
  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
  mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
  mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");


   //вытаскиваем id пользователя к которому прикрплены рефералы 
       $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$tempuser'"));//Запрос
  $tempref = $row["id"];

 //выбираем имя email пользователя по id
      $getref = mysql_query("SELECT email, first_name FROM `users` WHERE `ref`='$tempref'");


 if(!mysql_num_rows($getref)) exit ('Список рефералолв пуст');

  $i = 1;

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getref)){

     echo '<p># '.($i ++).' '.$row['first_name'].' '.  $em = $row['email'].' Кол-во оплаченных '.$total.'</p>';

  //считаем кол-во удачных оплат (равно 1) по email вот тут ошибка, переменная $em не подставляет текущее значение поля.  
$getsuccessales = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_zakaza) FROM `orders` WHERE `email`='$em' AND payment_status = 1");
         $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($getsuccessales);
                 $total = $myrow[0];
  }

?>
```

**Результат:**

[image: Результат]

Comment: зачем выбирать неподдерживаемую технологию динозавров для обучения? используйте PDO и подготовленные запросы.

Comment: @teran дело в том, что я узнал про PDO , только после того, как перешел к данному "модулю". В перспективе все буду переписывать в адекватном виде. Но к сожалению вопрос остается открытым. Все же , спасибо за вашу реакцию :)

Comment: Если вам приходится в коде на php в цикле читающем информацию из БД опять обращаться к БД, значит вы что то делаете не так. Любую информацию из БД можно получить одним запросом. Например в вашем случае `SELECT us.id, ref.email, ref.first_name, count(1)
  FROM users us, users ref, orders ord
 WHERE us.email='$tempuser' AND ref.ref=us.id AND ord.email=ref.email
 GROUP BY us.id, ref.email, ref.first_name` выполнит все, что вы тут делаете, останется только красиво вывести это на экран. Короче, учите SQL, он гораздо больше чем просто сохранение и получение сырых данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте вынести присваивание
и сначала подсчитать total

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getref)){
    $em = $row['email'];

   //считаем кол-во удачных оплат (равно 1) по email вот тут ошибка, переменная $em не подставляет текущее значение поля.  
   $getsuccessales = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_zakaza) FROM `orders` WHERE `email`='$em' AND payment_status = 1");
   $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($getsuccessales);
   $total = $myrow[0];

   echo '<p># '.($i ++).' '.$row['first_name'].' '.$row['email'].' Кол-во оплаченных '.$total.'</p>';
}
```

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо Вам, добрый человек! Все заработало!